# If $A=BC$, where $A$ and $C$ are given Laplacian matrices, how to calculate $B$?

Tags: matrices, laplacian, matrix-equations

Let me be more specific: If $A=BC$, where $A$ and $C$ are given [**Laplacian matrices**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix), how to calculate $B$? The graph corresponding to $A$ is a **directed ring**, which is strongly connected and $1_n$ and $1_n^T$ are right and left eigenvectors respectively. The graph corresponding to $C$ is a weighted **directed ring**, which is strongly connected but $1_n^T$ is no longer its left eigenvecor while $1_n$  is still its right eigenvector.

For example, $A=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1&-1&0\\0&1&-1\\-1&0&1\end{array} \right]$, that is , $A$ is a [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) ,singular, Laplacian matrix. $C=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1&-1/2&-1/2\\-2/3&1&-1/3\\-4/5&-1/5&1\end{array} \right]$ (singular, **non-symmetric** Laplacian matrix). Then how to compute $B$ if $A=BC$.

Note that $A, B, C$ are all **square matrices**. I **don't** want numerical solutions. There may be many solutions to this problem, so is there a formulated way to find **one** of them (maybe we can restrict $B$ to be Laplacian as well)?

Comment: Vectorizing the matrix equation, we obtain the linear system $$\rm (C^{\top} \otimes I) \, \mbox{vec} (B) = \mbox{vec} (A)$$ From here on, use Gaussian elimination, for instance.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo On a singular matrix?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Why not? Find the affine solution space, then un-vectorize. Ugly, but correct.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Wouldn't $$\lim_{t \to 0} \rm A (C + t I)^{-1}$$ also work?

Comment: What is the nullity of $\rm C$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo 1. It's an ill-posed problem. The solution is not unique. Assuming that limit exists, it only gives you one. OP should specify more about the solution they want. What if $A=C=0$, for instance? 2. Vectorizing seems useless - you can simply solve that equation row by row, dealing with $n\times n$ matrices instead of $n^2\times n^2$. 3. This question seems off-topic here in the present form. No motivation, badly specified (are the matrices square? Numerical solution or closed formula?), no hint of trying some basic linear algebra to deal with the singular system.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni That is why I asked about the nullity. I don't think vectorizing is useless, as it's essentially reducing the given problem to the simplest problem in linear algebra -- solving a linear system. This is obvious to you, but may be less obvious to the neophyte. Also, I think the question should be moved to MSE.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The nullity of $C$ is 1. In fact, I am considering the [Lapcian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) of which the corresponding directed graph is strongly connected. Therefore this kind of Laplician matrices have nullity 1. The background of this problem is related to Graph theory, so for convenience, I provided the simplify version of the problem.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $A$ is also a Laplican matrix, so it has nullity 1 as well if this information helps.

Comment: @Federico Poloni 1. Actually, I suppose $A$ and $C$ are [Laplacian matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) but not simply ZERO matrices. And if there are many solutions. what is the way to find one? (please don't think about $A=C=0$. It is too simple. 2. Why do you think vectoring is useless? Doesn't it simplify the problem? 3. Do you think singular matrices are not square? I want a closed formula instead of numerical solutions. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @winston $1_n$ spans both left and right null spaces of the Laplacian. Then the solution set is particular solution plus $\eta 1_n^{\top}$, where $\eta \in \mathbb R^n$ is a vector of parameters.

Comment: @winston Please edit your question adding more information and we can consider it for reopening. Zero *is* a Laplacian matrix: we did not knew your graph is connected before you wrote it in the comments. I just don't see anything you can do after vectorization that you couldn't already do considering each row of the system separately before vectorization. It just makes the matrices larger and the kernels more complicated.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I have updated my question. Note that the Laplacian does not necessarily correspond to a undirected graph, which means the Laplacian is not necessarily symmetric and therefore $1_n^T$ is not necessarily its left eigenvector. In this case, $1_n^T$  is not the left eigenvector of $C$.

Comment: @Federico Poloni I have updated the question.

Comment: @winston Wait, so is $B$ a Laplacian matrix, too, with the same nonzero structure as $A$?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni There are not specific requirements on $B$. However, it would be interesting if $B$ is required to be a non-zero Laplacian matrix.

Comment: I voted for reopening (3 now), and I'd answer if this was reopened. Quick version: chop off the last column of $C$ and $A$, which is superfluous because it's an equation that can be obtained by summing the others. Call $\hat{A}$, $\hat{C}$ the results. Now you can use (transposing) the formula for the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of a non-rank-deficient matrix, i.e., $B = \hat{A}\hat{C}^*(\hat{C}\hat{C}^*)^{-1}$, or normalize the last column of $A$ to be $1$ and solve the remaining $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ nonsingular linear systems for each row.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thank you for your help. Now this question is re-opened. Could you please provide a detailed answer since I could not quite understand your short version.

Comment: @winston You are right, there were a couple of mistakes in my comment that made it almost unreadable. I hope the answer is free of typos and mistakes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the system of linear equations is consistent, its solution is $B=AC^+$, where $C^+$ is the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $C$. Depending on the strictness of your definition of "closed formula", this may already fit the requirements. Otherwise, there are more explicit expressions. I list three alternatives in the following. Divide $A$ and $C$ into blocks
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12}\\
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix} 
=\begin{bmatrix}
B_{11} & B_{12}\\
B_{21} & B_{22}
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
C_{11} & C_{12}\\
C_{21} & C_{22}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
where the blocks labeled $22$ are $1\times 1$. Note that $C_{11}$ is invertible, because it is a submatrix of a singular irreducible [M-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix).

1. Remove the last column, which is superfluous since it is the opposite of the sum of the previous ones, to obtain the reduced linear system
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{11}\\
   A_{21}
   \end{bmatrix} 
   =\begin{bmatrix}
   B_{11} & B_{12}\\
   B_{21} & B_{22}
   \end{bmatrix} 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   C_{11}\\
   C_{21}
   \end{bmatrix}.  \tag{*}
   $$
   Now you can use the formula for the pseudoinverse of a matrix with linearly independent columns
   $$
   B = \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{11}\\
   A_{21}
   \end{bmatrix} 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   C_{11}\\
   C_{21}
   \end{bmatrix}^+ = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{11}\\
   A_{21}
   \end{bmatrix}
   \left(\begin{bmatrix}
   C_{11}\\
   C_{21}
   \end{bmatrix}^*\begin{bmatrix}
   C_{11}\\
   C_{21}
   \end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
   C_{11}\\
   C_{21}
   \end{bmatrix}^*.
   $$
2. Once you have removed the last column, you can choose $B_{12}$ and $B_{22}$ arbitrarily and solve for $B_{11}$, $B_{21}$ in (*), which is possible since $C_{11}$ is invertible.
3. If $u,v$ are norm-1 vectors such that $Cv=0, u^*C=0$, then another formula for the pseudoinverse is 
   $$
   C^+ = (C + uv^*)^{-1}-vu^*.
   $$
   You can prove this using the formula for $C^+$ based on the SVD of $C$ -- basically the idea is that we change the last singular value of $C$ from $0$ to 1, then invert, and undo the change.

Comment: But $AC^{+}$ is no longer a Laplacian....

Comment: @FelixGoldberg OP asked for a closed formula for *any* solution to the system, if I understand correctly. In any case, if one wants a Laplacian, it is easy to enforce it: the general solution is $B=AC^+ + xu^*$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and we can determine $x$ by enforcing $B1_n = 0$. This condition gives a valid choice of $x$ because $u^*1_n \neq 0$, as $u$ can be chosen with positive entries by Perron-Frobenius.

Comment: $CC^+$ does not necessarily equal to the identity matrix so $B=AC^+$ is incorrect.

Comment: @winston $CC^+\neq I$ if $C$ is singular, yet that formula produces one of the solutions to the linear system (when it is solvable). See [this paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Applications) or a textbook on applied linear algebra (such as Demmel or Trefethen-Bau).